# combining proxy server modules with my webapplication

Tags: java, proxy, mod-proxy

I want to implement a autmatic billing systen for one cybercafe.MEasning when some one want to surf net in my cafe he goes to attendent and attendent allocates him the pc and gives him the  passswd which is generated by the applciation and the passswd will be valid for specific time(session of 1 hr or so depending on customer needs).Now when customer goes to his pc and opens any site he must be first redirected to my webapplication which will ask for passswd .If he enters correct details he will be allowed to surf the net for that particular and if his time expires he has to get the timer renevewd fro attnedent or else he cant serf.

In short i want a readymade proxy server module in java that i can combine with my webapplication. As i will need to  implemet billing/ autontication based  on this thigs.

What approach can i use? What proxy moduels are available?

Answer (score 0):

The only Java proxy server I've encountered is [jsocks](http://jsocks.sourceforge.net/). It should provide the proxy features you want.

You can then write your own authentication on top of this to make it behave you want with regards to time based logins e.t.c. Quoting from the jsocks page:

> Authentication scheme is rather
>   simplistic, but can be extended, if
>   you know how to program in Java.

Comment: Apache HTTPd's mod_proxy? Yes, a little bit. But if you want info on that you'd be better off asking on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

I would use [CoovaChili](http://www.coova.org/CoovaChilli) or some other [captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) and then work the [RADIUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) part into the billing application.